# How to pass a custom jar file to maven jarsigner plugin for signing

Tags: maven, jarsigner

I have a maven build configuration where I do the following steps

1) Compile and build the jar file (ABC.jar) using the maven assembly plugin
2) Run proguard using maven-proguard plugin to shrink and obfuscate the jar file to get a resultant file as ABC-small.jar
3) Run the maven jarsigner plugin to sign the final jar ABC-small.jar

The problem is that the jarsigner plugin always picks the initial ABC.jar file generated from maven-assembly instead of ABC-small.jar generated from maven-proguard plugin.

How do I tell jarsigner plugin to pick the ABC-small.jar ?

Here is my maven-jarsigner config in pom file

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sign</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>

            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <!--  <storetype>pkcs12</storetype> -->
        <keystore>cert\keystore</keystore>
        <alias>applet</alias>
        <storepass>applet</storepass>
        <keypass>applet</keypass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/usage.html) say that the basic configuration signs the project jars and any *attached* jars.  Is ABC-small.jar attached to the project?  If it is not, try including the `<archive>` element in your plugin configuration.  Value should be the ABC-small.jar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
  <archive>${project.build.directory}/ABC-small.jar</archive>
  <keystore>cert\keystore</keystore>
  <alias>applet</alias>
  <storepass>applet</storepass>
  <keypass>applet</keypass>
</configuration>
```

In your configuration you have to mention the jar file path in  tag.

Adding more info of @user944849 explained.. if you want generate keystore for your appet use keytool-maven-plugin ..